# Question from pandas of resample from quantile function

Tags: python, pandas, quantile

```
import pandas as pd
new = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\cctsa\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\stock_2409.csv')
new['time'] = pd.to_datetime(new['time'])
new.set_index(new['time'], inplace=True)
print(new)
rule_type = '10T'
period_n = new[['ticket']].resample(rule=rule_type).quantile(0.75)
```

About question from pandas combine "quantile" function, it only show one result from this method, could python have a quick coding to show the result together of quantile(0.25, 0.5, 0.75) at same time?
Thanks give me a help.

Comment: Thanks your kindly feedback me. That's helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use if need processing numeric column `close`:

```
print (new['close'].dtype)

period_n = new['close'].resample(rule=rule_type).quantile([0.25, 0.5, 0.75])
```

Or if need procesing `close` column per `ticket`s:

```
period_n = new.groupby('ticket')['close'].resample(rule=rule_type).quantile([0.25, 0.5, 0.75])
```

Comment: [6642 rows x 6 columns]
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(2021-12-24 09:00:00, 0.25), (2021-12-24 09:00:00, 0.5), (2021-12-24 09:00:00, 0.75),
It only show up the "Empty data frame" without and result...
any way, thanks you so quick to feedback me.

Comment: @Chrisyu50d - is ticket numeric column? Answer was edited.